# Allows only one "." in Javascript during KeyPress

Tags: javascript, keypress

How to allow only one "." in **javascript** during **Keypress**?

I have a code here:

```
function allowOneDot(txt) {

        if ((txt.value.split(".").length) > 1) {

          //here, It will return false; if the user type another "."

         } 
}
```

Comment: And what if the user pastes in a bunch of periods? What if they edit the javascript in their console to completely ignore this check? Make sure you are handling validation correctly and not making too many simplifications.

Comment: Why is it wrapped in a `try`/`catch`?

Comment: Why the `try-catch`? what are you asking about?

Comment: `txt.value.split(".").length) > 2` and `input/keyup/keydown` event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will reiterate what I said in my comment before the answer:

> And what if the user pastes in a bunch of periods? What if they edit the javascript in their console to completely ignore this check? Make sure you are handling validation correctly and not making too many simplifications.

Now that we're proceeding at our own risk, here's how you would not allow a user typing more than one `.` (period) in a textbox:

```
document.getElementById('yourTextboxIDHere').onkeypress = function (e) {
    // 46 is the keypress keyCode for period     
    // http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html
    if (e.keyCode === 46 && this.value.split('.').length === 2) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygKHE/)

Comment: i still can  paste any number of dots

Comment: He said during key press not during paste. As jbabey has said javascript validation should never take the place of server side validation and should only be an addition to reduce the number of unnecessary submits to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd check `this.value.indexOf('.') == this.value.lastIndexOf('.')` instead of splitting though. Splitting will create new array on each key stroke, which shouldn't be desirable.

Comment: Also `keyCode` for dot is 190, not 46. Plus, you should return false if the length doesn't equal 2, instead of the other way around. Also `e.preventDefault()` wouldn't hurt :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to allow one dot, even in the event of a user pasting text inside it, you should use keyup, not keypress, and you could keep your last text value in case you need to restore it.
The drawback though, is that the input value will have already been changed, and you will see it getting corrected as you type.

```
(function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
    var prevValue = txt.value;

    function allowOneDot(e) {
        var dots = 0;
        var length = txt.value.length;
        var text = txt.value;
        for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
            if(text[i]=='.') dots++;
            if(dots>1) {
                txt.value = prevValue;
                return false;
            }
        }
        prevValue = text;
        return true;
    }
    txt.onkeyup = allowOneDot;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question for the multipurpose use of decimal, number & alphanumeric field types.

For field types 'number' and 'alphanum', parameter l (lower L) is the string length allowed.  For type 'decimal', it specifies the allowed number of decimal places.

```js
function allowType(e, o = 'number', l = false) {
    let val = e.target.value;
    switch (o) {
        case 'alphanum':
            if (l) {
                val = val.substr(0, l).replaceAll(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/gmi, '');
            } else {
                val = val.replaceAll(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/gmi, '');
            }
            break;
        case 'number':
            if (l) {
                val = val.substr(0, l).replaceAll(/[^0-9]/gmi, '');
            } else {
                val = val.replaceAll(/[^0-9]/gmi, '');
            }
            break;
        case 'decimal':
            let i = val.search(/\./gmi);
            if (val.length === 1) {
                val = val.replaceAll(/[^0-9]/gmi, '');
            }
            if (i >= 0) {
                if (l) {
                    val = val.substr(0, i + 1) + val.substr(i).substr(0, l + 1).replaceAll(/\./gmi, '');
                } else {
                    val = val.substr(0, i + 1) + val.substr(i).replaceAll(/\./gmi, '');
                }
            }
            val = val.replaceAll(/[^0-9.]/gmi, '');
            break;
    }
    e.target.value = val;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="allowType(event, 'decimal', 2)" placeholder="decimal">
<input type="text" oninput="allowType(event, 'number', 10)" placeholder="number">
<input type="text" oninput="allowType(event, 'alphanum', 5)" placeholder="alphanumeric">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="test" onkeyup="floatOnly(this);"/>



<script>
function floatOnly(i){
{
  if ((i.value).length > 0){else{i.value = i.value.replace(".." , ".");i.value = i.value.replace("..." , ".");i.value = i.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g , "");}}else{i.value = i.value="0";}}<script>
```

Comment: javascript solutions

Comment: The code in this answer contains syntax errors. Has bad ideas such as mixing 2 string replaces with regex replace and only works for some use cases